# Bundling stencil component with webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack-dev-server, webpack-2, stenciljs

Do anyone know how to bundling the web component created with stencil using webpack. I have multiple stencil components and need to create a bundle so that i can use it in other projects.

Answer (score 5):

Ionic has developed a [StencilPlugin for webpack](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-webpack), which allows to easily import components using the webpack bundler.

You may also be interested in [this excellent article](https://ionicframework.com/blog/using-webpack-with-web-components-built-using-stencil/) which explains in more details how to use the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The `stencil build` command normally bundles everything for you into the `components.js` file (or whatever your stencil config's `namespace` value is). So you shouldn't need to create your own bundle. If you are finding problems with the Stencil-built bundle, maybe have a look at https://stenciljs.com/docs/module-bundling.